# Closing an application and having it trigger a batch file to run?

Tags: file, batch-file, vmware

I'm trying to configure a virtual machine to start up from the machine being powered on.  I have that working.  Now I want to be able to shut down the entire machine once someone clicks Shutdown on the start menu of the virtual machine.

I'm using VMware with Windows 7 images, if that helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

invoke the start of the virtual machine with some kind of wait option and invoke shutdown afterwards.

Something like this

```
start /wait vmware-cmd cfg.vmx start 
shutdown -s
```

I don't have any vmware installed, I can't test it right now so I can't make sure the vmware-cmd doesn't return right away. If that is the case, then you must look for some loop mechanism in your bat file, something like

```
vmware-cmd cfg.vmx start 
:again
vmware-cmd cfg.vmx getstate >state.txt
if (state.txt contains some string indicating still running) goto again
shutdown -s
```